# Nextjs - back button with an explore/filter page

Tags: next.js, back

I have an /explore page allowing the user to filter product iD based on different select (category, type). It works via building (firestore) query parameters dynamically based on the selected values. The results are shown on that same /explore page.

If a user clicks on a product, it opens a dynamically generated page and everything works well. However, while clicking the back button it goes back to the /explore page with the default values/query (not the ones with the previous query).

Example :

- Default /explore showing all the sneakers
- user applies filters for brand and color => it triggers a dynamically generated query and renders it on /explore
- user clicks on one specific sneaker
- user clicks on the back button and lands on Default /explore (without the queries)
  However, I would like the user to land back on the /explore with brand and color filters...

Any ideas on how to do that ?
Thanks,
Max

Comment: Are you adding the filters as query parameters to the URL?

Comment: Yes I do. I get that : http://localhost:3000/explore?type=actions&field=category&fieldOp=%3D%3D&fieldVal=environnement&orderBy=&orderType= 
Should I fetch data on each re-render with the url query parameters ?

Comment: Could you share the code you currently have for that page?